# How to Get a Specific Value from an Object that is a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, selenium-chromedriver

I'll show my question with an example:

```
ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome");
```

Returns an object which is of type `Dictionary<string, object>`.
Inside this object there's a key `userDataDir` whose value I need.

Do I have to cast the object to a dictionary first or can I do some one-liner like:

```
chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome").GetType().GetProperty("userDataDir").GetValue()
```

The line above isn't compiled just to clarify.

Comment: Is the value within the dictionary itself a dictionary whose key you want to access?

Comment: have you even tried a google search perhaps `how to retrieve values from a Dictionary` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378465/retrieving-dictionary-value-best-practices

Comment: Are you saying the return type of `GetCapability` is `Dictionary<string, object>` or is the return type `object` and the specific object you are getting is a `Dictionary<string, object>` that you need to cast first?

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, the object is the dictionary that has the key.

Comment: @MethodMan Have you even read my question?

Comment: @juharr The return type is object, the question is if I must cast first.

Comment: @Moshisho Yes, the best course of action here is definitely to cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the cast on one line with `as`

```
var userDataDir = (chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>)["userDataDir"];
```

Of course this opens you up to possible null reference exceptions.  With C# 6 you could use the null-conditional to mitigate that.

```
var userDataDir = (chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>)?["userDataDir"];
```

But then you would not know if `null` was a value in the dictionary or if it was `null` because the cast failed.  The best bet is just to do this in multiple lines.

```
var dic = chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>;
if(dic == null)
{
    // The capability isn't a dictionary.
}
else
{
    var userDataDir = dic["userDataDir"];
}
```

Comment: Actually in my case it can't be null, because that will indicate that the functionality is wrong at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If the returntype of `chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome");` is `Dictionary<string, object>`

You can do as following, by casting the returned object to a Dictionary :

```
var capability = (Dictionary<string, object>)chrome.Capabilities.GetCapability("chrome");
var userDataDir = capability["userDataDir"];
```